# Editing html+css+js for a drop down nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found perfect code for drop down nav bar. But I'm stuck trying to edit it for my needs. Original complete code is situated here: https://github.com/vandoan/Elli/blob/master/dropDownNav.html
And how it looks: http://codepen.io/Xia-lj/pen/KdKOxw

**HTML:**

```
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div id="sections_btn_holder">
    <button onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel')">Navigator <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sections_panel">
    <div>
      Try adding things like more child div containers, links, buttons, menus, pictures, paragraphs, videos, etc...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #999;
}

div#topbar {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#666, #000);
  background: linear-gradient(#666, #000);
  height: 60px;
}

div#topbar > #logo {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 30px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #999;
}

div#topbar > #sections_btn_holder {
  float: left;
  width: 144px;
  height: 46px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

div#topbar > #sections_btn_holder > button {
  background: #F90;
}

div#topbar > #sections_panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 550px;
  background: #000;
  top: 60px;
  left: 160px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
}

div#topbar > #sections_panel > div {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 238px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #FC0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function toggleNavPanel(x) {
  var panel = document.getElementById(x),
    navarrow = document.getElementById("navarrow"),
    maxH = "300px";
  if (panel.style.height == maxH) {
    panel.style.height = "0px";
    navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9662;";
  } else {
    panel.style.height = maxH;
    navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9652;";
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to get: drop down nav bar like in example, but with three buttons "History", "Philosophy", "Physics". And each of this three sections must contain few books' names, e.g:

History:-

1. The History of Herodotus.
2. Titus Livius. The History of Rome.
3. Ivan Krypiakevych. The Great History of Ukraine.

"Philosophy":-

1. Works by Plato.
2. Nicomachean Ethics By Aristotle.
3. Fables And Aphorisms by Hryhorii Skovoroda.

"Physics":-

1. Stephen Hawking. A Brief History of Time.
2. Yakov Perelman. Physics for Entertainment.

I would be grateful to hear from anyone who may be able to help. I'm new in Web-development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obLwXQ) which is same example you provided just a bit modified on the HTML and CSS parts, inside `div#sections_panel` I've added 3 divs - *you mentioned 3 sections in the question* - with a `.sub_sections` class name.

```js
function toggleNavPanel(x) {
  var panel = document.getElementById(x),
    navarrow = document.getElementById("navarrow"),
    maxH = "300px";
  if (panel.style.height == maxH) {
    panel.style.height = "0px";
    navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9662;";
  } else {
    panel.style.height = maxH;
    navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9652;";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #999;
}

div#topbar {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#666, #000);
  background: linear-gradient(#666, #000);
  height: 60px;
}

div#topbar > #logo {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 30px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #999;
}

div#topbar > #sections_btn_holder {
  float: left;
  width: 144px;
  height: 46px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

div#topbar > #sections_btn_holder > button {
  background: #F90;
}

div#topbar > #sections_panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 550px;
  background: #000;
  top: 60px;
  padding:0 10px;
  left: 160px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
}

div#topbar > #sections_panel > .sub_sections {
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 258px;
  margin:10px 2px 0 0;
  color: #FC0;
  width:calc(31% - 10px);
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
#sections_panel > .sub_sections > a{
  color:#EEE;
  display:block;
  padding:10px 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #666;
}
#sections_panel > .sub_sections > a:hover{
  color:#333;
  background-color:orange;
}
#sections_panel > .sub_sections > h3{
  color:orange;
  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom:1px #222 solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div id="sections_btn_holder">
    <button onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel')">Navigator <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sections_panel">
    <div class="sub_sections">
      <h3>Search Engines</h3>
      <a href="//google.com">Google</a>
      <a href="//yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
      <a href="//bing.com">Bing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_sections">
      <h3>Social Networks</h3>
      <a href="//facebook.com">Facebook</a>
      <a href="//twitter.com">Twitter</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_sections">
      <h3>Video Networks</h3>
      <a href="//youtube.com">Youtube</a>
      <a href="//vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome version! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this......

Html

```
<div id="topbar">
<div id="logo">LOGO</div>
<div id="sections_btn_holder">
<button onclick="toggleNavPanel('The History of Herodotus,Titus Livius. The History of Rome,Ivan Krypiakevych. The Great History of Ukraine','sections_panel')">History <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></button>
<button onclick="toggleNavPanel('Works by Plato,Nicomachean Ethics By Aristotle,Fables And Aphorisms by Hryhorii Skovoroda','sections_panel')">Philosophy <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></button>
<button  onclick="toggleNavPanel('Stephen Hawking. A Brief History of Time,Yakov Perelman. Physics for Entertainment','sections_panel')">Physics <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></button>
</div>
<div id="sections_panel">
<div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   background: #999;
}

div#topbar {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#666, #000);
  background: linear-gradient(#666, #000);
  height: 60px;
}

div#topbar > #logo {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 30px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #999;
}

div#topbar > #sections_btn_holder {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 46px;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

div#topbar > #sections_btn_holder > button {
   background: #F90;
}

div#topbar > #sections_panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 550px;
    background: #000;
    top: 60px;
    left: 160px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
}

div#topbar > #sections_panel > div {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 238px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #FC0;
}
```

JS

```
function toggleNavPanel(text,x) {
     var panel = document.getElementById(x),
     navarrow = document.getElementById("navarrow"),
     maxH = "300px";
     var books=text.split(",");
     var html='';
     for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++){
         html+=(i+1)+") "+books[i]+"<br/>";
     }
     if (panel.style.height == maxH) {
          panel.style.height = "0px";
          panel.innerHTML="";
          navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9662;";
     } else {
          panel.style.height = maxH;
          panel.innerHTML="<div>"+html+"</div>";
          navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9652;";
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your version also very interesting! I will learn technical part. I'm sure I can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like http://codepen.io/fwpolice/pen/pqlgy

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    function t(t) {
        e(t).bind("click", function (t) {
            t.preventDefault();
            e(this).parent().fadeOut()
        })
    }
    e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
        var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").is(":hidden");
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
        if (t) {
            e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active")
        }
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")) e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
    })
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav {
    display: block;
    font: 13px Helvetica, Tahoma, serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav .button-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999;
}

.nav li a:hover, .nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active {
    background-color: #289dcc;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav li a:hover span, .nav li a.dropdown-toggle.active span {
    color: #fff;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu.active {
    display: block;
}

.nav li .dropdown-menu a {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      No dropdown
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="button-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Dropdown 1 <span>▼</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Drop Item 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Drop Item 2
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Drop Item 3
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      No dropdown
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="button-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
      Dropdown 2 <span>▼</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          asdf
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, design and goal (it is doing what I need) quite acceptable, but technical part is difficult for understanding (jQuery is unknown to me). I think better pure HTML/CSS/JS example. But anyway thank you! I will learn technical part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this toolbar is one for you: 
http://w2ui.com/web/demo/toolbar